# DAX IFERROR function in SQL SERVER

Tags: c#, sql-server, dax

I am new to DAX formulas.
What is to be done to use any DAX function in SQL SERVER procedure.
When i am simply using ISERROR function in SQL then i am getting this error::
'IFERROR' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Am i required to add some library or anything?
Pls reply.

```
declare @x int=10;
declare @y int=0;
declare @c int;
print IFERROR((@x / @y),Null);
```

Comment: Is any alternate function available in SQL SERVER to implement ISERROR functionality.the formula (@x/@y) is defined by user which may vary.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define variables this way in DAX. DAX is not a procedural language. DAX does contain IF .. but It wouldn't work with variables. As Variables are not expressions in DAX.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare **Var keyword to use a variable in dax language**,As DaX is not programming language